# redis ordered set queries conditioned on expiration

Tags: redis

I have an ordered set with key Z, and values:

1 "a"
4 "b"
3 "c"

In addition, I've keys a,b,c that are set to expire after varying time.

I want to find the highest ranking value in Z such that the value as a key has already expired. Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here's another approach:

As of Redis 2.8, you can subscribe to key-space or key-event notifications so that your Redis client can take some action when an expire happens. See http://redis.io/topics/notifications

As you receive expiration notifications, add an entry to another ordered set, say Zexpires. Then, when you need to perform your operation, you can use ZINTERSTORE to find the intersection, and get the highest ranking value using ZRANK on the result of the intersection.

Tip: If you're scaling horizontally, make sure you don't have multiple clients observing the key-space notifications and attempting to perform the same computation. If you have multiple instances of your Redis client, you may want to do things manually, as proteneer suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Redis has no expire hooks. What you can do, though, is have an ordered set in which the scores are the time in seconds since the epoch, so they are ordered by time, and the last ones will be the oldest. You can then check if they have expired by subtracting the time (now minus the score of the item in the list) in your application or with a Lua stored procedure.